# Clear form Text boxes on Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to clear all the texts boxes on register button click. Below is my attempt. When I click on the button, the texts still remains. Please advise. Thanks

```
<form action="#" class="signup" method="post" onsubmit="return signup();">
    <input type="text" id="signup-email" class="text-input" name="email" title="E-mail" autocomplete="off" tabindex="11" placeholder="E-mail">
    <input type="password" id="signup-password" class="text-input" name="password" title="Password" autocomplete="off" tabindex="12" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="password" id="signup-password2" class="text-input" name="password2" title="Confirm password" autocomplete="off" tabindex="13" placeholder="Confirm password">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="align-right">
                <button type="submit" class="signup-btn" onclick="this.form.elements['text-input'].value=''">Register</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
<button type="submit" class="signup-btn" onclick="this.form.reset();">Register</button>
```

Comment: I would like my register button to reset it. Not creating a new button. Thanks

Comment: great bro :). cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
   document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.signup-btn').click(function() {
    $('.signup input[type="text"]').val('');
  });
});
```

And you register button would be:

```
<button type="submit" class="signup-btn">Register</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add id attribute to form element. and then you can try this:

```
  <button type="submit" class="signup-btn" onclick="document.getElementById('formid').reset();">Register</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since he wants the form to reset it self automatically he can make a hidden reset button and make it click on submit.

```
<input type="reset" id="reset_button" style="display:none"/>
```

Then click the button by its id on submit of the form.

```
$('reset_button').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<button type="submit" class="signup-btn" onclick="$('form')[0].reset()">Register</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO `this.form.elements[]` is a collection array and you can access individual elements by passing either index or element name

For example, `this.form.elements[0].value=''`

OR

`this.form.elements['email'].value=''`, `this.form.elements['password'].value=''`

I am not sure if you can really pass the class name to it to access all elements with that class name. To reset all elements in the form, you can use `this.form.reset()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
First you need to edit your form tag like

```
<form action="#" name="form1" class="signup" method="post" onsubmit="return signup();">
```

Now add this script.

```
function resetForm($form1) {
    $form.find('input:text, input:password').val('');
}

resetForm($('#myform')); // by id, recommended
resetForm($('form[name=myName]')); // by name
```

Answer (score -1):

Add reset button to your form,

```
<button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Hi Kiran, I do not want to create a new button. I would like my register button to clear all my text boxes